# Unable to save off DB changes using Entity Framework

Tags: sql, database, save

I am pretty new to the EF world and am trying to understand why I am unable to save off changes to my phone record. I realize that I need to modify my entity but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have tried using context.xxxx but I am getting an error that context is not defined. What is the using for context? If I change the phone type for the same user I want to update the record with the new info.

Phone definition:

```
namespace NewSMS.DATA.EF
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Phone
    {
         public int Phone_ID { get; set; }
         public string Phone_Number { get; set; }
         public int User_PK1 { get; set; }
         public int LU_Phone_Type_PK1 { get; set; }

         public Nullable<bool> Available { get; set; }

         public virtual LU_Phone_Type LU_Phone_Type { get; set; }
         public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Code:

```
    if (phnMems != null && phnMems.Count > 0)
    {
        var smsPhn = new Phone { };

        foreach (var item in phnMems)
        {
            smsPhn.Phone_Number = item.Phone_Number;
            smsPhn.LU_Phone_Type_PK1 = item.Phone_Type_ID;
            smsPhn.User_PK1 = obj.User_ID;
                        
            Phone phoneInfo = db.Phone.FirstOrDefault(n => n.User_PK1 == obj.User_ID);

            if (phoneInfo == null)
            {
                 db.Phone.Add(smsPhn);
                 db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {                            
                 smsPhn.Phone_ID = phoneInfo.Phone_ID;  //keep userID
                 db.Entry(phoneInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
                 phoneInfo = smsPhn;
                 db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    } //End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

smsPhn.Phone_ID = phoneInfo.Phone_ID;  //keep userID
db.Entry(phoneInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;

In above code, you are assigning phone_ID in smsPhn object but updating phoneInfo object.

**Just a Suggestion:**
Move this declaration
var smsPhn = new Phone { };
inside foreach loop and call savechanges outside the loop.